# How to get/set text value of AutoCompleteTextView in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, autocompletetextview

This problem looks trivial but I can't find solution for Xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutoCompleteTextView` extends the `EditText` class so you should be able to get and set the text just by playing around with the `Text` property like this:

```
var autocompleteTextView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.AutoCompleteInput);
string currentText = autocompleteTextView.Text;
autocompleteTextView.Text = "New text";
```

Comment: Strange. How could I miss it. Thank you.

Comment: If you come from the Java world, you might be looking for the familiar setText and getText methods. These are however combined into one Text property in Xamarin.Android. Maybe that's how you missed it. :)